# Draft remains after creating a formatted appointment

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, appointment

I have Excel VBA that grabs data from the spreadsheet, then sends an Outlook calendar invite to team members and customers.

It's keeping a draft with no contacts in the To: field or subject. Would this be an issue with my code, or would this be an Outlook thing?

```
Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim olEmail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim olCal As Outlook.AppointmentItem
Dim olFolder As Outlook.Folder
Dim RequiredAttendee, OptionalAttendee, ResourceAttendee As Outlook.Recipient
Dim rtf() As Byte

Dim objOutlook As Object, objnSpace As Object, objFolder As MAPIFolder
Dim rngTo As Range
Dim rngCC As Range
Dim rngSUB As Range
Dim rngCALloc As Range
Dim rngCALstart As Range
Dim rngCALend As Range
Dim rngBody As Range
Dim myItem As Object

Dim oApp As Object
Dim oNameSpace As Namespace
Dim oFolder As Object

Sub SVN()
'Creates Outlook Calendar Site Visit Notification for one day onsite.'
    Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
    Set m = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    Set appt = olApp.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem)
        
    With ActiveSheet
        Set rngTo = .Range("J3")
        Set rngCC = .Range("J4")
        Set rngCALloc = .Range("J5")
        Set rngCALstart = .Range("J7")
        Set rngCALend = .Range("J8")
        Set rngSUB = .Range("J14")
    End With
    
    MsgBox "Verify Attendees:  Customer, Sales, Service."
            
    appt.MeetingStatus = olMeeting
    appt.RequiredAttendees = rngTo.Value
    appt.OptionalAttendees = rngCC.Value
    appt.Subject = rngSUB.Value
    appt.Location = rngCALloc.Value
        
    appt.Start = rngCALstart.Value
    appt.End = rngCALend.Value
    appt.AllDayEvent = True
        
    m.BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
    m.HTMLBody = Range("J16").Value
    m.GetInspector().WordEditor.Range.FormattedText.Copy
    appt.GetInspector().WordEditor.Range.FormattedText.Paste
    appt.Display
    
End Sub
```

Comment: FYI - `Dim RequiredAttendee, OptionalAttendee, ResourceAttendee As Outlook.Recipient`.  Only `ResourceAttendee` is necessarily an `Outlook.Recipient`.  The others are `Variant`...you need to explicitly declare all variable types, otherwise they default to `Variant`.  (This may not be the issue, just wanted to point it out.)

Answer (score 1):

You're effectively creating a mail item to format text from the spreadsheet and copy/paste it into the appointment ***and then never closing that mail item.***  See notated code below.

Simplest solution is likely to add `m.Close olDiscard` to the end.  More "effective" solution would be to remove the logic requiring a mail created solely for formatting of text into an appointment.

```
Sub SVN()
'Creates Outlook Calendar Site Visit Notification for one day onsite.'
    Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
    Set m = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem) '<--------------Make new mail item
    Set appt = olApp.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem)

    With ActiveSheet
        Set rngTo = .Range("J3")
        Set rngCC = .Range("J4")
        Set rngCALloc = .Range("J5")
        Set rngCALstart = .Range("J7")
        Set rngCALend = .Range("J8")
        Set rngSUB = .Range("J14")
    End With

    MsgBox "Verify Attendees:  Customer, Sales, Service."

        appt.MeetingStatus = olMeeting
        appt.RequiredAttendees = rngTo.Value
        appt.OptionalAttendees = rngCC.Value
        appt.Subject = rngSUB.Value
        appt.Location = rngCALloc.Value

        appt.Start = rngCALstart.Value
        appt.End = rngCALend.Value
        appt.AllDayEvent = True

        m.BodyFormat = olFormatHTML '<-----------Adjust new mail item bodyformat to HTML
        m.HTMLBody = Range("J16").Value '<-------Paste data from spreadsheet into mail item
        m.GetInspector().WordEditor.Range.FormattedText.Copy '<-----Copy the formatted text from mail item
        appt.GetInspector().WordEditor.Range.FormattedText.Paste '<----Paste into the appointment.
        m.Close olDiscard '<----This is new. Close the mail item and discard (no save)
        appt.Display


End Sub
```